# Javascript match Time frome Time String

Tags: javascript, regex, time, match

I have date like "HH:MM:SS CEST" and I want to match only "HH:MM:SS" without CEST or other string there.

Comment: You've stated what you want, how about posting what you've tried so far? Please read [Ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Subject: 12:25:47 CEST
Regex: \d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}
Tester: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string = "I have date like "07:12:45 CEST" and I want to match only "23:32:16" without CEST or other string there."

var m = string.match("(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))
```

### [Demo](http://regexr.com/39fpm)

Comment: is `67:12:45` a valid time?

Comment: then why your regex matches this `67:12:45`?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the regex methods posted here, you could try a date/time library like momentjs, which supports advanced parsing from strings. For your case you could use

```
moment('12:03:40 CEST', 'HH:mm:ss')
```

And then, if you want only the time part, you can use the format function, like this:

```
moment('12:03:40 CEST', 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm:ss')
```

This is slower than regex and requires a library to be included in your page, but you can do all sorts of date/time manipulations.

But if you only want to do the matching of a time string inside another string, then I also recommend regex.